# Java - Use a sentinel loop to re-prompt the user

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is keep getting floating point numbers from the user until they enter the string "quit".

What I have so far:

```
    System.out.print("Enter double: ");
    x = sc.nextDouble();
```

I have no idea how to check if the input is "quit" and then quit the program accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `nextLine()` to read a `String` so you can compare it with `"quit"`. If it is not `"quit"`, then you can convert that `String` into a `double` with the method `Double.parseDouble()`:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = ""; // You will reaceive input as String

    double x = 0.0;

    while (true) {
        input = sc.nextLine();
        if (input.equals("quit")) {
            break;
        }
        x = Double.parseDouble(input);
    }
}
```

**Note:** If the user inputs a `String` that is not `"quit"`, then you will get an `Exception`. This happens because you are trying to convert a `String` (that doesn't represent a number) into a `double`. If you *want* to handle this cases, add a `try-catch` clause to handle the exception.